# Mac 10.8 Guest Multiple Monitors in Virtualbox

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox, multiple-monitors, resolution

I've done a bit of searching and cannot seem to find an answer to my question.

I have Mac OS X Mountain Lion guest installed on a virtual machine using Virtual Box with a Windows 7 host. I've found how to change the screen resolution to allow 1440x900x32 by changing the boot.plist and the Virtualbox extra data entries. This is all working well.

I would like to enable a second monitor on the guest Mac OS X Mountain Lion so I can use both of my 1440x900x32 monitors while working in the OX X guest, however I have not found a way to configure more than one monitor aside from setting the Number of Monitors in Virtualbox Settings. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you,
Josh

Comment: Ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I settled for purchasing a second hand macbook pro. If you're adventurous, hackintosh is a possibility but it is against Apple TOC and not for the feint of heart.